# Create personalized sessions url using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I'm trying to create a app using React that sends an personalized posfix off my url, in a way that I can identify and organized later each client that access those url's.

E.g.:

```
root url: myapp.com/
```

What I'm looking for:

```
myapp.com/{randomstring}
```

Where "randomstring" will determine what session of my app the client is using.

Another example of this can be the Google Meet app:

Their root url is:

```
meet.google.com/{specific hangout id}
```

Where the complete url with the hangout id looks like this:

```
meet.google.com/abc-abcd-abc
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start):

The Route component accepts an array on the path parameter, so you can do something like this:

```
let paths = ['/accounts', '/home', '/users'];

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={paths}>
          <Test />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <App />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

This way, you can retrieve all routes from your database for example an store this in an array, and then using the above code snippet verify if the route is valid.